# How to filter exact words from a string?

Tags: javascript

My main objective is to check if the string contains array of words.
If the string contain $ in front of a word, I don't want it to check the string for array of words and want to straight way console.log it.

The problem I'm having is that its not checking for "Exact words".
For example if you put E, the text should show up since, there's no words that contains only 'E' however, its not showing up.

For instance:

```js
const res = `EU, U.S. REACH DEAL TO RESOLVE BOEING-AIRBUS TRADE DISPUTE
$BA`;
const filters = ["E", "OPEC", "Repo"];
if (!filters.some(element => res.includes(element))) {
  console.log(res);
}
```

Another method, I was thinking maybe using the split method and to check for every array item whether it's a filtered word or not.

Comment: there is a method Array.every works like Array.some but every condition needs to be satisfied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.split()` each string into an array of lower cased strings (delimiter is a space or a comma). If there's more than one string to be filtered, put them into an array

```
const strings = ['aaa, BBB, ccc', 'vhko nuu', 'String'];
let arrArr = strings.map(str => {
  return str.toLowerCase().split(/[,\s]/);
});
// arrArr = [['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], ['vhko', 'nuu'], ['string']]
```

Then run each string array of ***arrArr*** (array of arrays) through `.flatMap((strArr, idx)...` and each  string of each ***strArr*** (string array) through `.flatMap(str...`

```
return arrArr.flatMap((strArr, idx) => {
  return strArr.flatMap(str => {...
```

For each ***str*** (string) use `.includes(list)` and `.startsWith(char)` in a ternary to test if ***str*** is in the ***list*** or if it starts with a specific string (if the third parameter ***char*** was passed).

```
<IF> list.includes(str) ? <TRUE|THEN> [strings[idx]] 
: <ELSE IF> char && str.startsWith(char) ? <TRUE|THEN> [strings[idx]] 
: <ELSE|THEN> [];
```

```js
const strs = [
`EU, U.S. REACH DEAL TO RESOLVE BOEING-AIRBUS TRADE DISPUTE $BA`, 
`a, b, C, d, E, f`, 
`OPEC reaches agreement`, 
`This has opec., repo#, and a dollar$ so this should be ignored`
];

const words = ["e", "opec", "repo"];

const wordFilter = (list, strings, char) => {
  let arrArr = strings.map(str => {
    return str.toLowerCase().split(/[,\s]/);
  });
  return arrArr.flatMap((strArr, idx) => {
    return strArr.flatMap(str => {
      return list.includes(str) ? [strings[idx]] : 
      char && str.startsWith(char) ? [strings[idx]] : 
      [];
    });
  });
};

console.log(wordFilter(words, strs, '$'));
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use ES6 Array.filter() and arrow functions with expression body:**

```js
var words = ['get', 'help', 'set', 'moon', 'class', 'code', 'Get',  ];

var letter = 'e';

var word = "get";

const output = words.filter(x=>x.includes(letter));
console.log(output);

const output2 = words.filter(x => x.toLowerCase().includes(word));
console.log(output2);
```

Comment: Lets say, we change the letter variable and make it as a string,
How would I be able to filter the words?
because array [] just comes up

Comment: I have update my answer, hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var res = `EU, U.S. REACH DEAL TO RESOLVE BOEING-AIRBUS TRADE DISPUTE $BA`;

var filters = ["E", "OPEC", "Repo"];

if (filters.some(element => new RegExp('\\b'+element + '\\b').test(res))) {
  console.log(res);
}
```

Comment: I like this answer but how would I make it so, it not affected by capitalization
e.g. /gi?

Comment: This is case-sensitive so it will work for any case. try with your own by changing the case either in filters or in the string res.

Comment: I've made some changes `filters.some(element => new RegExp('\\b'+ element + '\\b', "i").test(res))` case insensitivity
Only problem I have left making 'U.S.' as a word, unfortunately, dot is causing problems

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get some idea from this example.[click here to see jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Janaka_Ravindra/7nb3xfsp/22/)

```js
var words = ['get', 'help', 'set', 'moon', 'class', 'code'];

var letter = 'e';

function find(words, letter) {

  letter = letter.split(''); //get it to as  object the  we can use it in every method as follwing

  return words.filter(function(word) { //get pne buy one word in words array

    return letter.every(function(char) {
      return word.includes(char); // return word including the letter that you request
    });
  });
}

const output = find(words, letter);
console.log(output);
```